# Android Fragments and sliding menu navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I have implemented a sliding menu navigation in my app like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXJMt.png).
When the user clicks an item in the sliding menu, a `Fragment` is created for the corresponding menu entry and it replaces any existing fragment. When the used navigates further away, for example, the top level Fragment is a `ThingListFragment` for a list of thigs, and he taps one to open a `ThingDetailFragment`, then I want to replace the sliding menu icon with an icon of a back arrow (so the user must first go back to the top level either by this button or by hardware back button before being able to access the menu).

[image]

At this moment I'm setting this manually and it's time consuming and error-prone if I have a lot of fragments like this.

Is there some clever way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a basic fragment class (for exaple: FragmentBasic) where you register your action bar icons, and then every fragment who needs these icons, extends your FragmentBasic class. after this just implement the extra layout you want